# Adding a specific margin to articles inside a section

Tags: css, margin, padding

I am trying to create a section with 6 articles in it that take all the width of the section and have `1.2em` space between the images:

[image]

In the picture I added, I'm showing two images. The first one is the current situation and the second one is what I want. This is the CSS code I'm using at the moment:

```
section {
margin: 0 10%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: pink;
margin-bottom: 50em;}

section article {
box-shadow: 0em 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
width: 33.3%;}

section article img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

I hope someone here knows how to fix my problem.

Thanks

Comment: where's your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
section {
  margin: 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: 50em;
}

section article {
  box-shadow: 0em 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: calc(33.3% - 1.2em);
  margin: 0.6em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></article>
  <article><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></article>
  <article><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></article>
  <article><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></article>
  <article><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></article>
  <article><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this:

```
section article {
box-shadow: 0em 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
width: 30%;
box-sizing:border-box;
margin: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
section {
margin: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: pink;
margin-bottom: 50em;
justify-content: space-between;
}

section article {
box-shadow: 0em 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
width: 32%;
  margin: 0 0 2%;
}

section article img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

```html
<section>
  
  <article><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/"></article>
  <article><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/"></article>
  <article><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/"></article>
  
  <article><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/"></article>
  <article><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/"></article>
  <article><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/"></article>
  
</section>
```